Is a 32 byte keylength good for scrypt when it comes to hashing passwords?
Given a scrypt configuration of cost=2^17 (131072), block size=8, and degree of parallelism=1, is a 32-byte key length sufficient for secure password hashing? What are the best practices in this scenario?

Depends on context. Where is this scenario coming from?

@RoyceWilliams This scenario is coming from storing password for a website.

But why have the other specific parameters been selected in advance?

I was reading about scrypt from https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html#scrypt and at that site, I found the recommended values for the other specific parameters.
